# Summarize multiple distributions into one, specifically in the topic modeling context

Tags: probability, distributions, topic-models

My specific case is this: There are a number of categories (Science, Health, Religion, etc.), each containing multiple documents. Assume for documents within each category, I perform topic modeling (LDA) with 10 topics ($k=10$). For example, for the Science category, each topic will correspond to Biology, Chemistry, etc.

The topic distribution, $\theta_{category=c}^d$, for each one of the documents, shows how likely it is that they are generated by each of those 10 topic. In this example, $\theta_{category=c}^d$ will be a list of size 10. I want to get the topic distribution over all documents of category $c$, $\theta_{category=c}$. A simple way that I have seen people use is to average each element of $\theta_{category=c}^d$:
$$ \theta_{category=c} = mean(\theta_{category=c}^d)$$
But it seems very naive. Is there a better, more rigorous way to combine all these distributions into one?

Comment: To clarify, you're looking to find the distribution of topics in each category's corpus? That is, you're not looking to share dependence shared among the categories; is that correct?

Comment: That is correct. I want to get topic distribution per category

Answer (score 1):

One idea, is that you could concatenate the documents of each category in one big document containing the whole category and infer the topic distribution $\theta_{category=c} $ of this concatenated document. Bear in mind though, that your topic model maybe sensitive to the **average length** of the initial simple documents. That is, if it's trained on more or less same length documents, then this concatenated document will be $N$ times longer, where $N$ is the number of documents to be concatenated. Maybe, if you use *tf-idf features* for each document you can alleviate this./

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not introducing any dependencies among the categories, you can continue to treat this as a single LDA model for each category's corpus.

In the notation of the [paper introducing LDA](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/blei03a/blei03a.pdf), you're looking for $\alpha$, the mean topic parameter for the corpus. I'm not sure which implementation you're using, but [R's `topicmodels` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/topicmodels/vignettes/topicmodels.pdf) can estimate this for you. The paper introduces a method for finding an empirical Bayes estimate of $\alpha$ in the appendices, in case you need to roll your own version.